# how do sort pandas dataframe by column LABEL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read some time series data and made a pd.DataFrame object out of it:
[image]

The dataframe is 1 row and 84 columns, each column's label is a datetime object so I can add more rows with different data to that date later. As you can see, the columns are out of order. This is causing my data to look incorrect when I print it in line graph form.

The only search results I'm seeing are about sorting an entire dataframe by the **values of a single column**. How can I sort my dataframe by the **headers of every column**, so that my columns are in chronological order?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`?

Comment: yup oops, rookie mistake thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your dataframe by multiple columns like this:

```py
df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
```

What it will do is sort your df by `col1` and then, if there are duplicate values in `col2` against a single value in `col1`, it will perform a sort again for `col2` values.